# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len() when printing the regression coefficient of the first column in dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to find the number of regression coefficients in the first column of my dataframe. My code raised

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv("master.csv")    
# Drop redundant features
X = df.drop(['suicides/100k pop', 'country-year', 'suicides_no'], axis=1)
y = df['suicides/100k pop']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression(n_jobs=4, normalize=True, copy_X=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

print(f"There are {len(model.coef_[0])} regression coefficients:")
print(model.coef_[0])
```

X_train

```
print(type(X_train))

> <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

y_train

```
print(type(y_train))
> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Traceback:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) /tmp/ipykernel_6232/341058392.py in <module>
>       1 # Check number of and values of coefficients
> ----> 2 print(f"There are {len(model.coef_[0])} regression coefficients:")
>       3 print(model.coef_[0])
> 
> TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with: "I want to find the number of regression coefficients in the first column of my dataframe". What mean lenght? It's just one number. It makes no sense at all. The answer below from _gtomer_ it's the correct one.

Comment: Answer(s) not helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you sound confused on the modeling part, which leads you to request invalid things in the programming part.

> I want to find the number of regression coefficients in the first column of my dataframe.

There is no such thing. By definition, the number of coefficients in linear regression is equal to the number of variables, i.e. columns in your array/dataframe; so, there will always be one and only one coefficient for the first column in your dataframe.

Similarly, your `print` statement:

```
print(f"There are {len(model.coef_[0])} regression coefficients:")
```

is incorrect; the number of your regression coefficients will be `len(model.coef_)`. `model.coef_[0]` is simply the first of these coefficients; it will always be a single number, and that's why `len(model.coef_[0])` will always produce an (expected and justifiable) error (single numbers do not have any length).

Demonstrating the above with the toy example available in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]]) # 2 variables/columns
# y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
```

Here, we have 2 variables (columns) in `X`, so it will be

```
len(model.coef_)
# 2
```

with

```
X.shape[1] == len(model.coef_)
# True
```

by definition.

(Notice that the intercept is not included in the coefficients; it is returned separately with `model.intercept_`)

So, in order to actually get what you seem to request in your `print` statement, you should change the statements to

```
print(f"There are {len(model.coef_)} regression coefficients:")
print(model.coef_)
```

keeping in mind that the reported number will not include the intercept.

The above commands in my example will produce the correct outcome:

```
There are 2 regression coefficients:
[1. 2.]
```

And if you also want to include the intercept term for completeness, you should add:

```
print("and the intercept term is:")
print(model.intercept_)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using [0] you are "calling" a specific value. It is a number therefore it has no len() which is a string function.

If you want to print out the len use:

```
len(model.coef_)
```

Comment: I only want to print out the first length of the `model.coef_` for the first column.

Comment: What is the output of: print(model.coef_[0])?

Comment: One float, for example: 4.2

Comment: This is why it cannot have length (len). It is an item - not a list. What does len(model.coef_) gives?

Comment: The number of coefficients that your Linear Regression has. Take a look to the first example of this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html). It will help you understand it better.